# Convergence in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Here is my question:

Let $\alpha_0, \dots, \alpha_{p-1} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ be such that $\alpha_i \equiv i \pmod{p}$ for all $i = 0,\dots, p-1$. Show that, for any $x\in \mathbb{Z}_{p}$, you can find an infinite sequence $(a_{n})_{n\geq 0}$, where each $a_n \in \lbrace\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{p-1} \rbrace$, such that 
$$x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_np^{n}.$$

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the class $\bar x$ of $x\bmod p^n$. Since $\Bbb Z_p/p^n\Bbb Z_p\simeq\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$, you can find
$$
m_n=a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+...+a_{n-1}p^{n-1}\in\Bbb Z
$$
such that $\bar x=\bar m_n$, where each $a_i\in\{0,1,...,p-1\}$.

Now observe that 
$$
m_{n+1}=m_n+a_np^n
$$
so that the sequence $\{m_n\}$ converges to $x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kp^k$ in $\Bbb Z_p$.